# "a que hora" ou "a que horas"?

Tags: concordância-nominal, número-gramatical

Tenho ouvido as duas formas na língua falada.  Serão as duas corretas inclusive na norma culta?  Alguma diferença entre as duas?

> - Você sabe me informar a que hora/horas começa o show?
> - Eles informaram a que hora/horas é o embarque?
> - A que hora/horas você pretende lavar o carro?

Comment: Curioso... a primeira frase soa-me estranha porque em Portugal «tu» indicaria registo informal mas «informar» indicaria registo educado ou semi-formal.

Comment: @ANeves Outros dois problemas em Portugal nessa frase: ou "saber-me-ias informar" ou "saberias informar-me" e o uso explícito do pronome. Mais natural: «Sabes dizer-me a que horas/hora começa o espetáculo?»

Comment: @ANeves e Artefacto - Na verdade eu deveria ter usado a terceira pessoa do singular para ficar mais como ptBR.  "Você sabe me informar..." Quanto ao uso de "informar", usamos muito a palavra quando pedimos uma "informação".  "O sr. saberia me informar onde é...."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não encontrei recomendações sobre este tópico em lado nenhum. De maneira que fui ver o que o uso literário consagra.

Como se vê no painel 1 dos resultados do Google Books, *a que horas* é de longe muito mais comum que *a que hora* (por exemplo, 1650 ocorrências de *a que horas é* contra 106 de *a que hora é*). Mas, como mostra o painel 2, esta preferência pelo plural inverte-se quando perdemos a preposição *a*: nós dizemos *a hora da partida (ainda não foi marcada)*, e não *as horas da partida*. E no entanto em qualquer dos casos *hora* e *horas* significam *momento* (*a que horas parte* = *em que momento parte*, *a hora da partida* = *o momento da partida*). Logo, não vejo argumento contra a forma minoritária *a que hora*.

**Resultados da busca no Google Books**

```
1.              é       chega       parte         sai       vai     vais
A que hora     106        25          52           34        52       1
A que horas   1650       366         360          506       424      70
```

---

```
2.         do espetáculo    do show   da reunião    da partida    da chegada
A hora           343           396         704          3940          1270
As horas           1             1           2            10             1
```

---

```
3.           de     de ir    de dormir    de você     de te     de te ires
É hora     59600     2690       1340        2950       216           1
São horas   6800      799        443           8       206          17
```

Uma possível explicação para a preferência por *a que horas* é que a resposta pretendida é uma hora exata:

> «A que ***horas*** começa o show?» «Começa ***às nove horas***.»

Já *a hora disto* e *a hora daquilo* aparece muito a seguir ao verbo *chegar*:

> Chegou a hora de ir para a cama (é verdade).

*Chegaram as horas* ou *chegou as horas de ir para a cama* soaria estranhíssimo. O Painel 3 mostra que o verbo *ser* já aceita bem *as horas de*, mas as últimas três colunas indicam que isto se deverá desproporcionalmente a Portugal. Foi o único aspeto em que detetei diferença entre Portugal e Brasil (no painel 2, a coluna do *show* deve ser praticamente só Brasil, mas tem o mesmo padrão que as outras; no painel 1, a última coluna deve ser desproporcionalmente Portugal, e também tem o mesmo padrão que as outras.)

Comment: Excelente trabalho de pesquisa.  Concordo que "chegaram as horas" soa muito estranho.  Uma pergunta, Jacinto, o "c" de "detectei" caiu em Portugal?

Comment: Sim, antes do AO escrevia-se *detectar*, mas o "c" não era pronunciado. Portanto com o AO caiu.

Comment: Mas nós aqui pronunciamos o "c".  E como ficamos?

Comment: Escreves com "c". É uma das palavras com grafia dupla, tal como *facto/fato*, só que aí são os portugueses que escrevem com "c".

Comment: @Centaurus: Eu (brasileiro) ainda misturo as versões de detectar e contactar, na maioria das vezes as falo dessa forma, pronunciando o "c", e me policio para não escrever assim.

Comment: @Luciano  Mas se nós pronunciamos o "c", temos que escrever com "c".  O "c" só caiu na escrita quando ele é mudo na fala.